# Create multiple records in a table using 1 form in MS Access 2013

Tags: forms, ms-access

I know this has been asked before, but I couldn't figure it out in my case.

I have a table called t_JOB, and one of the columns is "PO #". Each PO # can have multiple PO Line Items. So I created a table called t_PURCHASES_PO_ByLI which has the columns "PO #", "Line #" and "Line Amount". PO # from the t_Job table is a primary key and is a 1 to many relationship with the PO # in the t_PURCHASES_PO_ByLI Line Items table.

I want the user to be able to enter the PO # in the t_JOB table as well as the line # and line amount for as many lines items as they want in 1 form. Now after some research I added a subform and was able to do this BUT, it only worked if I entered 1 line # and line amount. I had the textboxes for more but it wouldn't send the values.

I understand forms are supposed to be for 1 record only, but in this case it would make sense for the user to be able to enter the PO #, and well as all of the line #'s and amounts associated with it all at once. How can I do this or is there a different way to go about solving this?

**Edit**

Here is what I enter in my form:

[image]

Notice how it only stores the value 5 for the Line #'s? The default values for each are 1, 2, 3 respectively. Only when the form first loads and I switch from the Line #1 textbox to the description #1 textbox does it change to 5. If I go and change it back to 1, all the values for line # switch to 1. They don't stay at 1, 2 and 3.

Also, notice how all of the description textboxes are the same? I don't want this to be the case, but whenever I edit one of the description boxes, it edits them all. How can I make them unique?

Here is what gets written to the t_JOB table:

[image]

Here is the data stored in the t_PURCHASES_PO_ByLI:

[image]

Also, I read up on Multiple-item forms, but I can't figure out how to add one as a sub-form. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your form, with some entered values? Is the subform a continuous form?

Comment: @Andre not sure what you mean by continuous form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subform `Line Items` seems to be a "single form", i.e. its [`DefaultView` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822539.aspx) is `Single Form`.

And you have 3 sets of controls, probably each of them with the same control source, therefore they will always show the same value.

Change the Default view to `Continuous Forms`, and remove all but one instance of each field (remove the #2 and #3 controls). Then you will be able to enter multiple records in the Line table.